# Сделать из номера телефона картинку и вывести на сайте

Tags: php

В базе mysql хранятся номера телефонов. Чтобы избежать спама и звонков у клиентов - нужно вывести эти телефоны на сайте в виде картинок. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Есть замечательная библиотека для работы  изображениями  - http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

            //height and width of the captch image
            $width = 180;
            $height = 30;

            //phone
            $phone="+7 (800) 000 0000";

            //create the image resource 
            $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 230, 80, 0); //background color
            $fg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);//text color

            //fill the image resource with the bg color
            imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg);

            imagestring($im, 5, 10, 8,  $phone, $fg);//imagestring 



            //tell the browser that this is an image
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            header('Content-type: image/png');

            //generate the png image
            imagepng($im);

            //destroy the image
            imagedestroy($im);
?>
```